# Android ViewPager inside fragment keeping fragments while Orienatation change

Tags: android, android-viewpager

As this Question is Many times asked but in my case the scenario is like on orientation change the view pager keeps the fragments of previous orientation.I tried to solve it by passing `getChildFragmentManager()` to the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` but in that case it is showing only first fragment after scrolling it is showing "BLANK" pages ,still first fragment is having data.
Also i tried changing `FragmentPagerAdapter` and added `destroyItem()` also tried by overriding `getItemPosition()` but no success.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: can you please show some code that you have worked on.

Comment: "ViewPageradapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{ public ViewPagerFragment (FragmentManager){ super(fm)} public Fragment getItem(){/*here i am returning fragment*/}} public int getCount(){ return 10}" this is my Adapter. How i am calling is new ViewPageradapter(getActivity().getSupportedFragmentManagaer()) .

Comment: What i was trying is by passing "getChildFragmentManager()" for this call , it is showing only once, for other pages is blank.(but i was scrolling blank pages , there are only those number of fragments which are required.)